# styled-components with typescript props issue applying on all same component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

sir i am using styled-components with typescript i have problem of sending props  below is the attached screenshot . Problem is i want to use same component and want for example second component margin-right   but its applying on both components.Thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: isn't cardProfileInfoImg undefined ? if you pass a undefined value you'll have the same result as passing no value.

Comment: Post code as plain text instead of screenshots